# Merging header in Matrix

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I want to merge the blue area of my matrix:

[image]

When selecting these 3 cells and right-clicking on them, I don't see the merge option, as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207131.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done as you're trying to merge cells in your Column Group (qwesa) with cells outside that group (gdfr).  I assume you need to use a matrix for your report, hence the column grouping.

Please see the MSDN reference on [Merging Cells in a Data region](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207131.aspx), which states

> Cells can only be merged within each area of a data region: corner, column headers, group definition (or row headers), and body. You cannot merge cells that cross area boundaries. For example, you cannot merge a cell in the data region corner area with a cell in the row group area.

If you do not need column groups, you should instead use a tablix where the desired merging options is available.